# Selenium driver.execute_script throws a error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

im trying to build a instagram bot with Python and Selenium...
Everytime im clicking the "upload image" button the file handler opens.

A cool dude suggested me to use this part of code.

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Neuer Beitrag']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**edit:**
there is now a new error, I was just a bit weird

[Selenium closing file handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69003823/selenium-closing-file-handler/69004075?noredirect=1#comment121978858_69004075)

but now it throws this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

You can find the full code here:
https://pastebin.com/hRx1dSsa

Could somebody please tell me whats wrong?
Thanks :)

Comment: What is `arguments` supposed to be?

Comment: `arguments` should be web element here

Comment: As far as I can tell, `arguments` is supposed to be an alias for "the arguments to this function".  But that script isn't inside a function.

Comment: @KaffeMitMilf :- A cool dude also must have suggested to not click on upload button, but to send the files directly .

Comment: yeah, but it wont work^^
it just loads a sec and thats it

Comment: then put some sleep before sending the keys. like `time.sleep(5)` or may be 10 secs, try

Comment: @cruisepandey
it wont work :(
idk what i am doing wrong

could u please help me?
https://pastebin.com/sXjZyafd

Comment: I don't have the emulator, I won't be able to simulate the exact scenario. :(

Comment: Element  wasn't rendered properly that is the reason you are seeing that Cannot read property 'click' of exception. To let it rendered you have to put sleep

Comment: @cruisepandey
it throws the same error :(
am i doing everything right?
https://pastebin.com/tuHEzj9P

Comment: No arguments should be 0 not 1

Comment: @cruisepandey yay, thank you :) now it throws a other error haha
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: arguments[0].click is not a function

Comment: I will look tomorrow man ! It's late in night here but .click is a function for sure

Comment: @cruisepandey thank you so much :)
have a good night and sleep well!

Comment: im curious are you using chromedriver? I can't seem to upload imgs from a browser :D

Comment: you ever try just using the submit() method?  ex: upload_btn.submit();  Did the browse dialog still appear?

Comment: @bilke yes, i am^^ 
here is the full code, may that helps
https://pastebin.com/VgdfaUCT

Comment: @cruisepandey thanks, i tried it and now it says 
argument[0].click is not a fuction :(
https://pastebin.com/6M3Tan3q

Comment: @JohnGordon could you please explain it to me^^

Comment: @KaffeMitMilf : looks like element was not rendered properly. Not sure mate, it generally works for me always.

Comment: what... thank you so much, could you please send me the code you used? 
I will try that on my raspberry tomorrow^^

Comment: @cruisepandey hey, I ran the code on a other pc and it still says, that click is not a function...
Maybe i am emulating a other phone?
Btw im trying to emulate the IPhone X

Comment: @KaffeMitMilf : I really can not test this, since I do not have any emulator to simulate this scenario.

Comment: @cruisepandey hey, figured out the problem, why the first method isnt working:
its the wrong input tag, i can only find 10, one of those is the update profile picture tag, but I cant find the upload tag^^